# How to implictly call parent class's constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I want to do following thing:

```
class P {
  P(int a) {
    // construct
  }
}

class C extends P {
}

// in main
int a = 2;
C foo = new C(a); // can I do this?
```

I want create child object C by calling parent class P's constructor without writing any constructor in class C like "super(a)". Is that possible?

The idea is that I have a lot of class like "class C" which needs the same constructor functionality as "class P". So I don't want write a constructor method each time I create a new similar class.

Thanks

Comment: You can't call a constructor with an argument without writing a constructor that takes the argument. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructors are not inherited. You will need to declare a constructor in `C` that takes an argument. It will need to invoke the appropriate superclass constructor (if you don't want the default superclass constructor to be called).

The only constructor you can avoid declaring is the default, no-arg constructor, and that only if you declare no constructors. That's because the compiler will generate one for you if you have no constructors declared. The compiler always inserts a call to the default superclass constructor unless you explicitly call a superclass constructor.

Note also that if you do not explicitly call a superclass constructor and there is no default constructor in the superclass, you will get a compile-time error.

EDIT: If you have "lots of classes like class C", then an alternative to writing a lot of constructors is to use a [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). You can have all the classes implement a default constructor and provide a separate `init()` method that takes a standard set of arguments. The factory method would accept a `Class<? extends C>` object and some initialization arguments, generate a new instance (using the default constructor), and call its `init` method with the initialization arguments. That way you only need to override the `init` method for those subclasses that need special handling (always remembering to call through to `super.init`).

Comment: just like:public class B{protected int a;} class C extends B{proctected void init(int a){this.a =a;}} class Factory{ public static C getC(Class<? extend C> c,int a){C cInstance = c.newInstance(); cInstance.init(a);return cInstance;} class D extends C{@override procted void init(int a){super.init(a);...}}?

Comment: @user2245634 - I'd put `init` in `B`. Also, the factory method would be a generic method in `B`; you don't need a separate class. `C` and `D` would not need to override `init` for the sake of initializing `a` (although they might want to for other initialization).

Comment: thanks,but if  factory method pattern must use factory class to produce instance,or call new B() and so on will omit init method

Comment: @user2245634 - The idea is to pass `B.class` as an actual argument to the factory method. It internally uses `classArg.newInstance()` rather than the `new` operator to create an instance of whatever class was passed. Explicitly coding the class to be instantiated defeats the present purpose of using any kind of factory pattern.

Comment: yes,use classArg.newInstance(),but also need to call init method after that

Comment: @user2245634 - Yes, that's the idea. The type parameter to the generic factory method would be `<T extends C>`, and the class argument would be `Class<T>`. Then, since `C` declares an `init` method, the factory method can call it. Because of polymorphism, if the actual class passed as an argument overrides `init`, the overridden method will be called. I fail to see why a factory method won't work for this.

Comment: That's why java is so annoying and slow to write. I now have to implement 7 constructor overloads just because this language totally lacks convenient features.

Answer (score 4):

- A constructor implicitly calls the parameter-less constructor of it's immediate super class(only if there's no explicit call)
- When you define your own constructor,the default constructor would not be created.

---

So,in your case Class `C` has a default constructor which would try to implicitly call the default constructor of Class `P` which doesn't exits and would fail.

So,you have to do it this way

```
class P 
{
    public P(int a) 
    {
    // construct
    }
}

class C extends P 
{
    public C(int x)
    {
       super(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: A default constructor implicitly calls the parameter-less constructor of it's immediate super class **only** if the default constructor does not explicitly call a superclass constructor. However, that's true of _any_ constructor, default or not.

Comment: @TedHopp ohh yes..indeed..its applicable to any constructor..edited the ans..thx

Comment: Well.. we must also note that _super(x)_ must be the very first line in the child class constructor.